# Spring Boot - how to get authentication details from HttpServetRequest in my Request interceptor?

Tags: java, spring-boot, interceptor

I want to get authentication details like `userId`, `companyId` from my request interceptor, from `HttpServletRequest`. I have request interceptor and I have to fetch companyId of the currently logged user to perform a certain logic.

My Controller:

```
@PostMapping(consumes = "application/json")
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.CREATED)
 public IdDto createTa(Authentication auth,...)
```

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class GlobalInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {
    private final TaService taService;

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(@NonNull HttpServletRequest requestServlet, @NonNull HttpServletResponse responseServlet, @NonNull Object handler) {
        taService.checkIfRequestAllowed();
        return true;
    }
```

Is it possible?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Inside your method use the following to get the UserDetails and you must cast it to your Details object. Whatever you use to your Authentication. The method returns `Object` which needs to be casted to a specific `UserDetails` object that you use

```
UserDetails ud = (UserDetails) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getDetails();
```

Just remember to register this interceptor after the interceptor that you already have to check for authentication

Or you can just add `@Order(Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE)` in `GlobalInterceptor` so that spring handles this interceptor as the last one in the order that already exists.

Comment: I thought that I can fetch details directly from Authentication object from my controller/request.. because I think SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() can reduce performance when we have really a lot of requests that are handled by my interceptor?

Comment: Or maybe I'm wrong, maybe calling ((AuthenticationDetails) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getDetails()).getCompanyId(); on each request will not impact performance significantly?

Comment: Or maybe your solution is the only one? i have not found any information on the internet about how to extract data from a request